# Is it possible to create a `SQLReader` (like a `TextLineReader`) to read data from a database in TensorFlow?

Tags: database, tensorflow, reader

TensorFlow provides readers (eg. `TextLineReader`) to read records from various file formats directly from the TensorFlow graph (as opposed to reading the data from a client then pushing it to the server using placeholders).

Is there a way to create an arbitrary reader, eg. one that would read from a SQL database? I could export the database to a supported file format, but it's not always practical.

Comment: This is possible, but you'd need to look at the way that the TextLineReader op kernel is implemented on the C++ side. There are some base classes and interfaces that would lend themselves to something like a database table access, but it's also not straightforward to implement.

Comment: Thanks Pete, I was hoping to avoid C++, but that's ok. I'll look into it.